# Computing the order of an Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm studying for an algebra exam and in the past paper I keep seeing questions very similar to this:

> Compute the order of the abelian group
>   $$\left<x_{1},x_{2},x_{3} \mid x_{1}+3x_{2},x_{1}-2x_{2},-x_{1}+x_{3}\right>.$$

But I'm not really sure how to do this, I've looked through my notes but can't  find anything to help. 
Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

We have $x_3=x_1$ and $x_1=2x_2$, i.e. the group is generated by $x_2$. The first two relations yield $5x_2=0$, thus the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$.

In general you solve such a problem by using the Fundamental Theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, which gives you an algorithm to describe the isomorphism class of a group given by generators and relations. If the number of generators and relations coincide, you can compute the order as the determinant of the matrix given by the coefficients of the relations. (If the determinant is zero, the group has infinitely many elements)

Comment: See the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form).